# Cannot delete folders in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am having a problem deleting folders I create from Outlook 2013.

I can delete some folders in Outlook but not others. Even though I created all of these folders, it will not let me delete them.

Our Outlook is set up to automatically log in, we do not have an option for logging in.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: add error message to your question.